# JSON To Object. Problem with Generic Lists

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to map JSON to a object structure. First some code

My Delphi DTO:

```
type
  TElement = class
  private
    FItem: string;
  public
    property Item: string read FItem write FItem;
  end;

  TJsonTest = class
  private
    FItems: TObjectList<TElement>;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Items: TObjectList<TElement> read FItems;
  end;

constructor TJsonTest.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FItems := TObjectList<TElement>.Create;
end;

destructor TJsonTest.Destroy;
begin
  FItems.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

Here is the JSON I want to map to the above structure

```
{ 
   "items":[ 
      { 
         "item":"Item"
      }
   ]
}
```

Then the problem:

The following line raises an Exception, because the parser expects an Array and not a list.

```
jsonTest := TJson.JsonToObject<TJsonTest>('{"items":[{"item":"Item"}]}');
```

To overcome this problem I've tried to create an Interceptor

```
type
  TGenericListFieldInterceptor = class(TJSONInterceptor)
  public
    procedure ObjectsReverter(Data: TObject; Field: string; Args: TListOfObjects); override;
    function ObjectsConverter(Data: TObject; Field: string): TListOfObjects; override;
  end;

{ TGenericListFieldInterceptor }

function TGenericListFieldInterceptor.ObjectsConverter(Data: TObject; Field: string): TListOfObjects;
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  list: TList<TObject>;
begin
  list := TList<TObject>(ctx.GetType(Data.ClassInfo).GetField(Field).GetValue(Data).AsObject);
  Result := TListOfObjects(list.List);
  SetLength(Result, list.Count);
end;

procedure TGenericListFieldInterceptor.ObjectsReverter(Data: TObject; Field: string; Args: TListOfObjects);
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  list: TList<TObject>;
  ListOfObjects : TListOfObjects;
begin
  list := TList<TObject>(ctx.GetType(Data.ClassInfo).GetField(Field).GetValue(Data).AsObject);
   //<-- Problem: List is nil 
end;
```

And then ofcause modify my DTO:

```
  TJsonTest = class
  private
    [JSONReflect(ctObjects, rtObjects, TGenericListFieldInterceptor, nil, true)]
    [JSONOwned(false)]
    FItems: TObjectList<TElement>;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Items: TObjectList<TElement> read FItems;
  end;
```

My problem are in `TGenericListFieldInterceptor.ObjectsReverter` when trying to get the the list (`FItems`)  in which I have add the elements into, it is nil!

So in short: 
  In `TGenericListFieldInterceptor.ObjectsReverter` how to I get the object instance of FItems?

I'm using Delphi 10.3.3

** ***UPDATE*** **

After some debugging and looking into @UweRaabe's solution I've located the problem.

First thing where I forgot to use REST.Json.Types so JSONOwned wasn't called and there for my object where freed and that got me my list!

But the next problem where a bit harder to crack: I now have my list, but `Args` in `TGenericListFieldInterceptor.ObjectsReverter` where allways **nil**. After some time I found out that this was caused by the fact that ObjectType on my `TJSONUnMarshal` descendant where **nil**! No matter how hard I tried I could'nt get it initialized on the instance that where used inside `TJSONUnMarshal`.

After some more debugging I've located the problem: `TJSONUnMarshal.FieldReverter. Thats the method responsible for making an instance of my JsonReflect attribute.

Here is the first part of the method:

```
function TJSONUnMarshal.FieldReverter(Field: TRttiField): TJSONInterceptor;
var
  fieldAttr: TCustomAttribute;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if Field <> nil then
  begin
    // First check for individual Attribute
    try
      for fieldAttr in Field.GetAttributes do
        if fieldAttr is JsonReflectAttribute then
          Result := JsonReflectAttribute(fieldAttr).JSONInterceptor;     
   ..
      end;
    except

    end;
  end;
end;

JsonReflectAttribute(fieldAttr).JSONInterceptor creates the instance but due to the typecast  `JsonReflectAttribute(fieldAttr)` it is allways on the original `JsonReflectAttribute` class  not on my descendant `TGenericListFieldInterceptor`. Form here I see two ways ahead:
```

1) Edit in the original unit (`REST.JsonReflect`). 
  That's not an option in my World!

2) Code Redirect!

So I choose option 2.

In general I created a new version of TJSONUnMarshal.FieldReverter and at runtime, replaced the original one with mine.

In the new version I set the `ObjectType` property of my `TJSONInterceptor`. Since I know this Attribute are placed on a TObjectList descendant I can get the Class from the Add Method:

```
function TJSONUnMarshalFix.FieldReverter(Field: TRttiField): TJSONInterceptor;
var
  FieldAttr: TCustomAttribute;
  RttiType: TRttiType;
  RttiMethod: TRttiMethod;
  RttiParameter: TRttiParameter;
begin
  Result := nil;

  if Field = nil then
    Exit;

  try
    for FieldAttr in Field.GetAttributes do
      if FieldAttr is JsonReflectAttribute then
      begin
        Result := JsonReflectAttribute(FieldAttr).JSONInterceptor;

        RttiType := Field.FieldType;
        RttiMethod := RttiType.GetMethod('Add');

        if RttiMethod <> nil then
          for RttiParameter in RttiMethod.GetParameters do
            if RttiParameter.Name = 'Value' then
              if RttiParameter.ParamType.IsInstance then
                Result.ObjectType := RttiParameter.ParamType.AsInstance.MetaclassType;
      end;

  except

  end;
end;
```

I've created a small demo linking it all together
http://borrisholt.dk/Stackoverflow/GenericListReflect.7z

*Please notice:*  This is just the first version, with a sunshine scenario.

Comment: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-26848 contains a test case that also covers your problem. It is fixed in Delphi 10.3.3, so if you are on that version you should be able to derive a solution for your problem based on the test case types.

Comment: I cant access that page ;

It seems that you have tried to perform an operation which you are not permitted to perform.

If you think this message is wrong, please contact your JIRA administrators.

Comment: I can't access that page either.  Same error.

Comment: @UweRaabe This is beta QP report, it is not publicly accessible.

Comment: Damn! Seems someone changed the security level. I am pretty sure I filed the report for public access. I created another download: https://www.uweraabe.de/downloads/TestJsonReflect.zip

Comment: @UweRaabe I've updated the question, with a small demo, inspired on your solution. Place an answer and I'll close  the question.